# Java NoSuchElementException on nextInt

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I'm fairly new to all this, but i'm practicing for a Texas Computer Science UIL event and i'm working on a practice problem, but i have run into this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at bridge.bridge.main(bridge.java:28)
```

Here's my code. I honestly have no clue whats wrong with it besides being awful to look at.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class bridge {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("bridge.dat"));
    int convoys = input.nextInt();
    int vehicles;
    int weight = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int speedholder;
    int checker = 0;
    boolean placeholder = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < convoys; i++){
        vehicles = input.nextInt();
        for(int y = 0; y < vehicles; y++) {
            if(!placeholder) {
                placeholder = true;
                weight += checker;
                speedholder = input.nextInt();
                if(speedholder < speed || speed == 0) {
                    speed = speedholder;
                }
            }
            else {
                checker = input.nextInt();
                if(weight + checker > 42) {
                    placeholder = false;
                }
                else {
                    weight += checker;
                    speedholder = input.nextInt();
                    if(speedholder < speed || speed == 0) {
                        speed = speedholder;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(speed);
        speed = 0;
        weight = 0;
    }
    input.close();
}
}
```

it prints out "5" before giving the error. And heres what my input file looks like:

```
2
8
10 10
5 25
40 5
35 15
12 23
30 20
42 25
8 30
10
42 10
23 30
40 5
2 10
1 20
4 30
6 28
28 3
17 8
35 10
```

Any help is appreciated. I did look around for similar questions, but this seemed a bit more complex of an error, as i have done a few programs like but never got this error before, but i also could have just done something really stupid.

Comment: please fix your title with correct camel-case

Comment: check using `hasNextInt()` before calling `nextInt()`. And whenever in doubt, check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())

Comment: You seem to be miss reading the "vehicles" section, for each vehicle, you MUST be reading two `int`s, but you are only reading one...

Comment: Yeah this would be easier to explain if I could add the whole document in but it's printed out. But basically the first number is the number of convoys going across a bridge. The next is the number of vehicles in that convoy, and all the lines with 2 ints are weight and speed of each vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

When a `Scanner` throws a `NoSuchElementException`, it means you're trying to read from the scanner after you reached the end of the input.

If you want to find out if you're at the end of the input, you can use `hasNextInt`.

Go from there.

Comment: Opinion: consider a while loop `while(input.hasNextInt())` you're not actually referencing `i` and these methods are more iterator than array. The answer above is most likely it!

Comment: Yeah this is what i would normally do, but the way the input file is formatted and how the program is written is supposed to make that process unnecessary.